# Instantiate Class from method return and pass data to constructor PHP

Tags: php, instantiation

I have notification classes called ProductNotification, OrderNotification, etc, these have a mail method which returns another class which holds further data for the sending of emails:

```
class ProductNotification {
    public function mail()
    {
        return ProductMail::class;
    }
}
```

```
class OrderNotification {
    public function mail()
    {
        return OrderMail::class;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to instantiate the ProductMail class from the method, the following doesn't work and I'm not sure how to pass through another variable `$data` to the constructo.?

```
class BaseNotification {
    public function toMail()
    {
        return (new $this->mail())->to($email)->send();
    {
}
```

I know that if mail() was a property on the class instead, that this would be possible and I can pass through `$data` to the constructor as the following works, but is this possible from a method?

```
class ProductNotification {
    public $mail = ProductMail::class;
}
```

```
class BaseNotification {
    public function toMail()
    {
        return (new $this->mail($data))->to($email)->send();
    {
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to have `mail()` method `return new ProductMail();`?

Comment: Or store the class as a property instead of a method return.

Comment: You could store the class as a local variable in `toMail` and then instantiate the variable.

Comment: Because I need to pass `$data` through to the ProductMail constructor, I've already shown that I am aware that I can store it as a property. But because of the way other parts of the class is structured, it would be cleaner to keep things consistent by keeping it as a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the class as a local variable in the `toMail` method and then instantiate it.

```
class BaseNotification {
    public function toMail($data)
    {
        $mail_class = $this->mail();

        return new $mail_class($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this, I guess tunnel vision and coding late in to the night after a hard days work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an object from a method call, but you can do so from a variable. So just assign the method's return call to a variable:

```php
class ProductNotification extends BaseNotification {
    public function mail() {
        return ProductMail::class;
    }
}

class OrderNotification extends BaseNotification {
    public function mail() {
        return OrderMail::class;
    }
}

class BaseNotification {
    public function toMail()
    {
        $data = [];
        $class = $this->mail();
        return (new $class($data))->to($email)->send();
    {
}
```

Though it might be cleaner to just use the `mail()` method to build the mail:

```php
class ProductNotification extends BaseNotification {
    public function mail($data) {
        return new ProductMail($data);
    }
}

class OrderNotification extends BaseNotification {
    public function mail($data) {
        return new OrderMail($data);
    }
}

class BaseNotification {
    public function mail() {
        throw new \Exception("not implemented");
    }

    public function toMail()
    {
        $data = [];
        return $this->mail($data)->to($email)->send();
    {
}
```

Comment: You're the Michael Jordan of getting in just too late :)